# Simple mathematical function returning NaN; manual calculation returning numeric

Tags: r, function, nan

I'm having a strange issue with a custom mathematical function in [R]. My ultimate goal is to plot several sections of a piecewise function using calls to curve().

As part of this process, I wrote simple [R] functions for each section of the piecewise mathematical function:

```
gain.func <- function(x){x^0.88}
loss.func <- function(x){1.5*x^0.88}
```

Strangely, both of these functions return NaN for negative arguments (but work just fine otherwise).

Any idea why this might be the case?

As a sanity check, I had [R] do the calculation with a negative argument "by hand" (i.e., I simply replaced x with -2 in the expression 1.5*x^0.88), and the answer came back as a value of type numeric.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't raise a negative base to a fractional exponent. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers). With regard to your sanity check, you probably had a precedence error, e.g. `1.5*-2^0.88` is not the same as `1.5*(-2)^0.88`; the latter returns `NaN`.

Comment: Ah, okay, that does seem to be the issue. Thanks, @bgoldst!